# prove the convergence of the following series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $0 < d_n < 1$ with $\sum d_n$ divergent, then the two series $$\sum d_{n+1}\left[(1-d_0)\cdots(1-d_n)\right]^p$$
$$\sum\frac{d_{n+1}}{\left[(1+d_0)\cdots(1+d_n)\right]^p}$$

are convergent, for every $p>0$. I think it's enough to show the convergence of the first one, because by substituting $1-d_n' = \frac{1}{1+d_n}$ one can reduce the second series to the first one (almost, except for a bounded factor). I don't really have any ideas on how to prove this. Can you help me?

Comment: Yep I noticed. I was referring to the previous comment. Anyway, I still don't understand the second inequality between the sums. Why is it so?

Comment: So you think that this does not hold in general for $p>0$?

Comment: $S_{n+1}^p = S_{n+1}S_{n+1}^{p-1} < S_{n+1} S_n^{p-1}$.  This gives you the second inequality and proves convergence for all $p > !$.  Perhaps $p> 1$ is a typo.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the proof is correct when $p>1$ and the two series are connected by your correct thinking about transforming from $d_n$ to $d_n'$ (along with the details I gave below).

Comment: Yes! You mean $>$ in the previous comment though. Alright, I'm gonna upvote your answer and see maybe if you can come up with a counterexample for $0<p\le1$. Deal? :)

Comment: Thanks.  I'm looking at $p \leqslant 1$ now.

Comment: If the series diverges for $p=1$, then it diverges for all $p < 1$ because $\frac{1}{[(1+d_0) \cdots (1+d_n)]^p} \geqslant \frac{1}{(1+d_0) \cdots (1+d_{n})}$.  Also it is not hard to show that $\sum \frac{d_{n+1}}{S_{n+1}}$ diverges -- but this was used as an upper bound and does not prove divergence of the original series.  Nevertheless we are close to an answer.  It would be worth asking a followup question. There was a lot embedded in this problem.

Comment: Yes I appreciate your answer! Thank you very much. I will probably make another question. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S_0 = d_0$ and $S_n = \sum_{j=0}^n d_j $.

We have $(1+d_0)\cdots(1+d_n)\geqslant 1 + d_0 + \cdots + d_n \geqslant d_0 + \cdots + d_n + d_{n+1} = S_{n+1}$.

When $p > 1$ there exists a positive integer $m$ such that $\frac{1}{m} < p-1$ and

$$\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{d_{n+1}}{\left[(1+d_0)\cdots(1+d_n)\right]^p} \leqslant \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{S_{n+1}- S_n}{S_{n+1} ^p}  \leqslant  \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{S_{n+1}- S_n}{S_{n+1}S_n ^{p-1}} \\\leqslant  \sum_{n=0}^N\frac{S_{n+1}- S_n}{S_{n+1}S_n ^{1/m}}$$

Note that

$$\frac{S_{n+1}- S_n}{S_{n+1}S_n ^{1/m}}= \frac{1- \frac{S_{n}}{S_{n+1}}}{S_n^{1/m}}= \frac{1- \frac{S_{n}}{S_{n+1}}}{1- \frac{S_{n}^{1/m}}{S_{n+1}^{1/m}}}\left(\frac{1}{S_{n}^{1/m}} - \frac{1}{S_{n+1}^{1/m}} \right), $$

where the term $x = \frac{S_n^{1/m}}{S_{n+1}^{1/m}}= \left(\frac{S_n}{S_{n+1}}\right)^{1/m} \in (0,1) $ since the sequence $S_n$ is increasing .

By Bernoullis' inequality, we have $x^m = [1- (1-x)]^m \geqslant 1 - m(1-x)$ which implies that $1- x^m \leqslant m(1-x)$ and, substituting for $x$,

$$1- \frac{S_{n}}{S_{n+1}} \leqslant m\left(1- \frac{S_{n}^{1/m}}{S_{n+1}^{1/m}}\right)$$

Thus,

$$\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{d_{n+1}}{\left[(1+d_0)\cdots(1+d_n)\right]^p} \leqslant m\sum_{n=0}^N\left(\frac{1}{S_{n}^{1/m}} - \frac{1}{S_{n+1}^{1/m}} \right) = \frac{m}{d_0^{1/m}} - \frac{m}{S_{N+1}^{1/m}}$$

The series $\sum d_n$ diverges to $+\infty$ which implies that $m/S_{N+1}^{1/m} \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$ and the sum on the LHS converges, with

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{d_{n+1}}{\left[(1+d_0)\cdots(1+d_n)\right]^p} \leqslant \frac{m}{d_0^{1/m}}$$

---

For the first series, taking $d_n' = d_n/(1-d_n)$, we have

$$1- d_n = \frac{1}{1+d_n'}, \quad d_{n+1} = \frac{d_{n+1}'}{1+d_{n+1}'},$$

and

$$d_{n+1}[(1- d_0) \cdots (1-d_n)]^p = \frac{d_{n+1}'}{\left[(1+d_0')\cdots(1+d_n')\right]^p(1+d_{n+1}')} \leqslant  \frac{d_{n+1}'}{\left[(1+d_0')\cdots(1+d_n')\right]^p}$$

Now you can prove convergence using the result for the second series, after showing that divergence of $\sum d_n$ implies divergence of $\sum d_n'$.

Comment: The previous bound $(1+d_0) \cdots (1+d_n) > d_0 + \cdots + d_n$ is replaced with the better bound $(1+d_0) \cdots (1+d_n) > 1+ d_0 + \cdots + d_n > d_{n+1} + d_0 + \cdots + d_n$ since $d_j < 1$ for all $j$.

Comment: I posted an answer where I prove that we cannot have divergence for $p = 1$ in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to show that we cannot prove in general that the series diverges for $p = 1$ as @RRL suspected. We can prove that the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\cdots(1+a_n)}$$ is for $a_n$ positive invariably convergent. One can show easily by induction that, if we let $S_n$ be the partial sums of the series, then $S_n = 1-\frac1{D_n}$, where $D_n = (1+a_1)\cdots(1+a_n)$. Thus, since the product $\prod(1+a_i)$ either diverges to $+\infty$ or converges, it follows that the sum converges. We can use this result for the problem. Let $d_n$ be the general term of a divergent series; if $d_n$ is monotone decreasing, then $$\sum \frac{d_{n+1}}{(1+d_0)(1+d_1)\cdots(1+d_n)}\le \frac1{(1+d_0)}\sum \frac{d_{n}}{(1+d_1)\cdots(1+d_n)}$$ and the result follows by the previous.

I will edit this post if I can come up with a proof for $p \le 1$.

Comment: why the downvote? Would you care to explain so that I can understand if I'm wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I just took a look at this and offset that downvote.  Hit and run downvotes are clearly not helpful.  The argument for the sum with $a_n$ in the numerator is correct, but it does not carry over to the second part because we are not given that $d_n$ is decreasing. Where did this problem come from?

Comment: The problem is from Knopp's theory and application of infinite series. I assumed $d_n$ decreasing just to show that in that case we can have convergence for $p=1$. Of course it's just a particular case.